# Visual Studio 2017 intellisense saying namespace is used like a class, compiles fine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio out of literally nowhere started complaining that I'm using InsanityStore (which is a class) as a "namespace". I'm 100% sure that nowhere in the entire solution I defined a namespace "InsanityStore". The program compiles fine but intellisense keeps screaming at me to fix it.

Anyone knows how to get rid of this error?

[image: Image Of The Problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have something bad cached.  The easiest way to fix that is to quit visual studio, and then delete the .vs directory in your solution directory.  You’ll lose your set of open windows, breakpoints and other solution specific stuff but you’ll also force it to rebuild the cache that has the issue by doing this.

Comment: Thanks a million!